# Is Azure Log Analytics and App Insights Resilient to DataCenter Failure within an Azure Region

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, disaster-recovery

Is app insights and log analytics redundant within a given Azure region (i.e. East US)? In other words, if a single DC within East US goes down, will App Insights and Log Analytics continue to function?

If yes, can you provide a link proving this? If no, what would an appropriate DR plan look like to ensure logging (both AI and Log Analytics) is resilient to failure?

Comment: Since it's no response here, I suggest that raise this issue to [application insights home page on github](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues).

Comment: I went there to do that, but was met with this: "This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only."

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding (working in advisory support for Azure), no, both services currently store the data as LRS. I believe replication across regions is a roadmap goal for some point in the future.

Here's the one link that mentions this:

> Data is stored encrypted at rest in Azure storage, to ensure data
> confidentiality, and the data is replicated within the local region
> using locally redundant storage (LRS).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-security#3-the-log-analytics-service-receives-and-processes-data

The only current workaround I am aware of is that the Windows Log Analytics agent allows you to multi-home (send data to two or more workspaces). If you wish to hedge against regional outages, you can ingest the data in another region, but you will pay full costs for ingestion etc. in that region.

Multi-homing for Linux is still in the works as far as I know.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/10852986-multihome-agents

I'm not aware of any workaround for App Insights.